# Does putting a filter over my slicer visual only slice the values that are shown in the dropdown list but does not actually filter the data?

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, report, visualization

I was playing around with my dashboard, and I noticed that when I select individual components on my slicer, the values I get in my bar graph is correct, but when I select "Select all", the values include those that are not supposed to be included (after some digging around), for instance, I only want sales amount made from 2023 till now, but clicking select all will include sales amount from beyond 2023. How I went around this was by creating a calculated column to pick out the sales year and decide whether or not to include the, by using IF(..) and when I use this column as a filter on my page, only then when I select 'Select all', I will get correct values in the specified date range, which led to my question above.